# Can the Widget Configuration Activity eliminate a crowd from my app in the widget picker?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget app with 12 distinct widget layouts possible.  At present, it will crowd the system widget picker with 12 entries because I need to list all of the classes in the manifest or they will not execute.  Is there a way to handle the widget xml info and layout definitions so that all 12 are declared but only 3 of them display in the widget picker?

To be specific, I created collection backed stackview and listview layout objects. There are 3 different types of content to go into those layouts, and I specify 2 sizes for each layout for convenience (phone size and tablet size). I extend base provider and base service (view factory) classes to create the specific size/layout/content combinations. I have all of the provider and service class names enumerated in the manifest.  Can I have this AND limit the app to displaying only the 3 types in the widget picker?

Is there a design for widgets I can use where the configuration activity can set things up?  In other words, can I use the configuration activity to dynamically size the widget, regardless of what might be set in the widget's info xml file from the app manifest?  Can the configuration activity set the layout object (stackview/listview) at runtime and override the android:initialLayout tag?  My guess would be to set the initialLayout to have both and then declare one as visible and the other as gone in the widget provider's update method.  Does the initial remote view get created in the Configuration Activity?

It feels like I can use the normal/large and x-large layout folders to trim my list to 6 in the system's widget preview window.  I would prefer to have only 3, one for each type of content. I would be grateful for any guidance from the experts, even a simple answer like "that should work but I have not done it."

Thanks and regards,

PS - noteworthy - this is an open source project on Github called WikiWidgets. The 3 types of content are the photo of the day, the featured article of the day, and geo-tagged articles from Wikipedia.

Comment: "I would prefer to have only 3, one for each type of content" -- then why did you not do this? You are the one who created "2 sizes for each layout". Nobody forced you to. Use resizeable app widgets for tablets instead.

Comment: Actually, they are resizeable.  Your comment is appreciated but does not offer the guidance that was requested.  If you don't know, then you don't know.  Perhaps you do not agree that it is helpful for users installing the app on both a tablet and a phone to be able to choose the start size.

I have not yet finished implementing the configuration but it looks like the widget configuration activity is flexible enough to allow me to have one entry in the widget picker for all 12 widget possibilities.

Guidance from an expert would be great...

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, can I use the configuration activity to dynamically size the widget, regardless of what might be set in the widget's info xml file from the app manifest?

No.

> Can the configuration activity set the layout object (stackview/listview) at runtime and override the android:initialLayout tag?

Whoever uses `AppWidgetManager` to update the app widget (configuration activity, `AppWidgetProvider`, etc.) can specify whatever it wants for the layout. However, that has no impact on the size -- you still have whatever size your metadata asked for, modulo any user changes for resizeable widgets.

> Does the initial remote view get created in the Configuration Activity?

Anything in your app can set up the `RemoteViews` for the app widget (configuration activity, `AppWidgetProvider`, a background service that downloads data and updates the app widget, etc.). However, that has no impact on the size -- you still have whatever size your metadata asked for, modulo any user changes for resizeable widgets.

> Actually, they are resizeable

In which case, just let the user resize them.

> Your comment has a lousy tone

You shot yourself in the foot, then asked us why your foot hurts. My comment was trying to point out that your foot would not hurt if you would avoid shooting it.

> and does not help much with regards to the configuration activity

Largely because the configuration activity has nothing to do with the app widget size.

> I thought it might be helpful for users installing the app on both a tablet and a phone to be able to choose the start size.

Then move the question of what the *content* is ("photo of the day, the featured article of the day, and geo-tagged articles from Wikipedia") to the configuration activity. You can have multiple starting sizes based on screen size by having multiple versions of your app widget metadata in appropriate resource sets (e.g., `res/xml/widget.xml` and `res/xml-large/widget.xml`).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got as far as having the xml-xlarge and xml folders to get the size dynamically.  The question is still about the configuration activity.  Can I switch the layout type using that activity.  If I include both types of layout I can, setting one layout visible and the other gone and then check visibility for the different components in my base provider and viewfactory classes.  Have you got an example of a widget config activity to refer to?   My foot doesn't hurt but I can sharpen my tongue for you.

Comment: @Beth: "Can I switch the layout type using that activity" -- see 2nd paragraph of answer. "Have you got an example of a widget config activity to refer to?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: Do you foresee a problem if I put both a stack and a list into the layout xml and then switch the layout type in the config activity so that only one of the two is visible? If folks have written some complex config activities they might have more answers for us. (Note, everyday Android users may not know how to resize widgets, thus, a convenient way to choose the size could be valuable)

Comment: @Beth: "Do you foresee a problem if I put both a stack and a list into the layout xml and then switch the layout type in the config activity so that only one of the two is visible?" -- that might work. It would seem to be simpler just to use different layout XML resources with your `RemoteViews` depending on which flavor they choose from your configuration activity.

Comment: Yes, I have done different layouts.  It is easier and it works great.  Howevever, this requires multiple entries which is the root of the question.  How much can I configure the widget?  I will try to get to a single widget picker item with 12 actual configurations dished out by the config activity.  I got as far as starting the configuration activity and displaying a widget when a widget is picked from the picker.  I can update stackOverflow when I find more time to work on the code and to implement the resulting choices in the provider and view factory classes.

Comment: @Beth: "Howevever, this requires multiple entries which is the root of the question" -- it requires multiple layout files, but it should not require multiple `<provider>` elements. "How much can I configure the widget?" -- other than size, you are in control over just about everything else. You can't change `updatePeriodMillis`, but you can accomplish the same thing yourself via `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Well - the initial layout is in the xml info file along with the size, so, I'm not sure I understand your response.  If there is more than one layout, then there is more than one info file which would be more than one entry in the widget picker.

Comment: @Beth: If you look at the constructor of `RemoteViews`, you will notice that it takes a layout resource ID. This, not `android:initialLayout`, controls what the user sees as you populate the `RemoteViews`. The `initialLayout` is *only* used *before* you first update the app widget using `AppWidgetManager`. Hence, you can supply whatever layout resource ID you want at runtime to `RemoteViews` and have a single `<provider>` element in the manifest.

Comment: That sounds good.  It might solve the sizing issue too.  Explicit sizing in the layout could override the minimums set in the info.xml.  I will have to update this article as I found out what works.